# asp.net core RC2 iis hosting

Tags: url, iis, localhost, asp.net-core, hostname

I have hosted asp.net core app in IIS on window server 2012 R2 Standard. My site works fine when I use localhost based URL on the machine but when I try to access the URL using host name/machine name from network computer it does not work. What do I need to do to make it accessible from other computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be different reason for this:

- Check your firewall to make sure your port 80 is open.
- Check that the hostname point to the IP URL of your server.

What is the **http code** returned by the it does not work?

Tool:
Enter the Domain and IP, make sure they point to the same place.

http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.htm

Comment: I have another app running on same machine using .net 4 which is accessible so no firewall or network issues. 

IE says page cannot be displayed
FireFox says the connection has timeout. 

I think asp.net core require some additional configuration to make it accessible to network.

Comment: read the log of the application, read the event viewer of windows to see traffic.

Comment: If he is using IIS the I think the default ports (80/443) will be open, no?

Comment: You were right about the firewall. The port 80 was open which was being used for other app that worked. Asp.Net Core app was using 8081 and that was blocked by the Firewall. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If firewall isn't the problem, and the site works via localhost on the server, make sure your IIS bindings are correct.  Right click site, edit bindings, verify the domain / ip / etc match how you're trying to access it.